# Compare and find object using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to compare elements using streams from a request with two subelements against an object that contains these elements as child objects.

For example:

base object:

```
public class Domain {
    long id;
    List<Software> softwares;
    List<Hardware> hardwares;
}
```

child objects:

```
public class software {
    String part;
    String did;
}

public class hardware {
    String part;
}
```

I have a request with array of `softwares` and one `hardware`  like below

```
    {
    "softwares":[
        {
        "part":"abc",
        "did":"000"
        },
        {
        "part":"bcd",
        "did":"001"
        } 
    ],
    "hardware": {
        "part":"caltop"
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to find a `Domain` streaming list of `domains` which contains all the softwares in the request and hardware with condition that Domain may have more softwares and hardwares but it should just need to contain softwares and hardware to be able to consider a match.

I started with

```
                 domains.stream()
                .filter(domain -> domain.getSoftwares().contains(request.getSoftwares())
                        && domain.getHardwares().stream().anyMatch(request.getHardware()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but this is wrong and I couldn't move ahead with anything. I want try doing it using streams

Comment: Why are you using `getSoftwares().equals(req.getSoftware())` ? doesn't getSoftwares return a list and getSoftware return a single element? If both are lists, you probably want a containsAll; otherwise if the getSoftware is a single element you want contains.

Comment: Sorry thats a typo. Request contains list of software. Updated. But even that is wrong statement as I am comparing with all the softwares in the request against all the softwares in domain. I only needed to see if softwares from request exist in domain and there may be extra softwares in domain but still thats a match

Comment: What does `request.getSoftwares()` return?

Comment: list of softwares from request @TheHeadRush

Comment: why don't you use this: domains.stream()
                .filter(domain -> domain.getSoftwares().contains(request.getSoftwares())
                        && domain.getHardwares().contains(request.getHardware()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like so:

```
domains.stream().filter(domain -> 
domain.getSoftwares().containsAll(request.getSoftwares())
&& domain.getHardwares().contains(request.getHardware()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the trick is to use containsAll for the list of softwares, and there is no need to stream the hardwares. just use contains.